# Updating only few properties using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I recently started using Automapper. I have big database table with 50 properties. 
I want update table using Automapper but only few selected properties will be passed using viewmodel.

To make my question simple I wrote small console program.

```
internal class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

internal class PersonContract
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PersonContract Person1 = new PersonContract { NickName = "Dan", LastName = "Smith"  };
        Person Person2 = new Person { FirstName = "Robert", NickName = "Rob" };

        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonContract, Person>();


        Mapper.Map(Person1, Person2);

        Console.WriteLine(Person2.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine(Person2.NickName);
        Console.WriteLine(Person2.LastName);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My output is 
NULL
Dan
Smith

I was expecting 
Robert 
Dan
Smith

Because if Person1 is not passing "Firstname" then Person2 should keep old value.
Obviously I am not understanding it properly.
Can anyone explain this issue? And let me know how to get the output I was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default *Automapper* will copy all properties whether they are null or not, but you can set a condition to be met by all members using `ForAllMembers` and `Condition` methods.

In your case you can check for `IsSourceValueNull` property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonContract, Person>()
      .ForAllMembers(cfg => cfg.Condition(rc => !rc.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for it. I knew there has to be some easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your out put is right, first name value of your source is null,automapper just copy values for you. If you want to get out put as you mentioned, I suggest you write a custom type converter, see - http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters for overview.